# How do Amazon Cognito User Pool device tracking configuration in the console map to corresponding CloudFormation template configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

The Cognito User Pool console has a page for configuring device tracking:

[image]

The corresponding configuration in the AWS::Cognito::UserPool looks like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-deviceconfiguration.html):

[image]

***How do the four combinations of these properties' possible values map to the three options in the console?***

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this reply to a GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/448#issuecomment-673222930) which gives the following mappings:

**Always, MFA Yes**

```
DeviceConfiguration:
  ChallengeRequiredOnNewDevice: true
```

**Always, MFA No**

```
DeviceConfiguration:
  ChallengeRequiredOnNewDevice: false
  DeviceOnlyRememberedOnUserPrompt: false
```

**User Opt In, MFA No**

```
DeviceConfiguration:
  DeviceOnlyRememberedOnUserPrompt: true
```

**User Opt In, MFA Yes**

```
DeviceConfiguration:
  DeviceOnlyRememberedOnUserPrompt: true
  ChallengeRequiredOnNewDevice: true
```

**No** 
Omit `DeviceConfiguration`